# ¿Cómo crear una variable condicional dentro de una función en javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, condiciones, function, else

Estoy creando una calculadora de crédito para calcular el pago mensual de un prestado, estimando numero de cuotas y con una tasa de interés diferente para cada linea crediticia.

necesito crear una variable condicional tipo

Escoge tu linea de crédito

Si escogiste el Item(index) # 0, 5, 6, 10, 16 de la lista

```
var G = document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex
```

la variable será:

```
var S = y*0.00342;
```

si escogiste cualquier otro Item, la variable será:

```
Var S = y*0.00042;
```

como puedo incluir esta condición dentro de mi función?

comparto el HTML y el Javascript

HTML:

```
    <select id="list">
    <option value="2">Avance de nomina</option>
    <option value="0.75">Calamidad</option>
    <option value="0.95">Compra de vehiculo</option>
    <option value="1">Compra de cartera</option>
    <option value="0.95">Compra de moto nueva</option>
    <option value="1.85">Consumo</option>
    <option value="0.8">Crediaportes</option>
    <option value="1">Cuota inicial compra vivienda nueva</option>
    <option value="1">Educativo</option>
    <option value="1.8">Electrodomestico</option>
    <option value="2">Gerencia</option>
    <option value="1.95">Ordinario con codeudor</option>
    <option value="1.95">Ordinario sin codeudor</option>
    <option value="1">Pago impuesto y reforma vivienda</option>
    <option value="1.5">Prima</option>
    <option value="1.6">Turismo y recreación</option>
    <option value="1.85">Convenios y seguros</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="currency-field" id="valor" data-type="currency" placeholder="$1,000,000" 
     autocomplete="off " min="0"  onkeypress="return noenter()"> 
    <br>
    <br>    
    <input type="number" name="currency-field" id="cuotas" placeholder="Meses" autocomplete="off " 
     min="0" onkeypress="return noenter()">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="CALCULATOR">
```

y el JavaScript de la función matematica... la Variable `var S` es la que necesito que sea dependiente

```
function INTERES() {
var x = document.getElementById("list").value;
var y = document.getElementById("valor").value;
var c = document.getElementById("cuotas").value;
var P = x/100;
var A = 1+P;
var E = Math.pow(A, c);
var PE = P*E;
var I = E-1;
var PEI = PE/I;
var T = y*PEI;
var G = document.getElementById("list").selectedIndex;
var S= y*0.00342;
var S1 = y*0.00042;
var payment = T+(S,S1)+2000;
document.getElementById("CALCULATOR").innerHTML = formatter.format(payment.toFixed());
}
```

Gracias por sus respuestas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer esto:

```
let S = [0, 5, 6, 10, 16].includes(G) ? (y*0.00342) : (y*0.00042);
```

Ingresas en un array todos tus posibles indices para que se cumpla tu condición y según a eso variará el valor de **S**.

La función includes buscará el valor de **G** en el array de indices.

Un consejo que te doy es que pongas nombres más descriptivos a tus variables.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! eso era

No sabía como iba esa sintaxis... como puedo buscar para profundizar al respecto?

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

    const select = document.getElementById("list");

    let y = 1;

    function handleSelect(ev){
        const G = ev.target.selectedIndex;
        const differents = [0, 5, 6, 10, 16];

        let S = differents.indexOf(G) != -1 ? y * 0.00342 : y * 0.00042;
        console.log(S);
    }

    select.addEventListener("change", handleSelect);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="list">
        <option value="2">Avance de nomina</option>
        <option value="0.75">Calamidad</option>
        <option value="0.95">Compra de vehiculo</option>
        <option value="1">Compra de cartera</option>
        <option value="0.95">Compra de moto nueva</option>
        <option value="1.85">Consumo</option>
        <option value="0.8">Crediaportes</option>
        <option value="1">Cuota inicial compra vivienda nueva</option>
        <option value="1">Educativo</option>
        <option value="1.8">Electrodomestico</option>
        <option value="2">Gerencia</option>
        <option value="1.95">Ordinario con codeudor</option>
        <option value="1.95">Ordinario sin codeudor</option>
        <option value="1">Pago impuesto y reforma vivienda</option>
        <option value="1.5">Prima</option>
        <option value="1.6">Turismo y recreación</option>
        <option value="1.85">Convenios y seguros</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Hice un ejemplo minificado de tu código para poder ver como podemos hacer ello, en primeras, los `select` tienen un evento llamado `change` el cual siempre se ejecuta cada vez que el valor del `select` cambia, por lo tanto podemos aprovechar el evento change no solo para obtener desde el mismo el valor actual seleccionado por el select, si no tambien para poder hacer esta `variable - condicional` que indicas, esto de variable condicional se le conoce como `shorthand assignement`,
y funciona de la siguiente manera:

la interrogación es el `if` de toda la vida mientras que los dos puntos son el `else`, en pocas palabras siempre debe haber un valor, ya sea que se cumpla la condición o no, entonces aquí:

```
let S = differents.indexOf(G) != -1 ? y * 0.00342 : y * 0.00042;
```

Lo que estamos haciendo es comprobar si el elemento seleccionado es alguno de los elementos que tendran  un valor diferente, en cuyo caso, el valor será y * 0.00342, de lo contrario será y * 0.00042.